# Create a dictionary of bin values with different bin sizes - python

Tags: python-3.x, binning

I would like to create a dictionary of bin values with different bin sizes and increments. For example,

```
Starting increment is 5, through 10 (e.g. 0-5, 6-10)
Then, increments of 10, through 100 (e.g. 11-20, 21-30...91-100)
Then increments of 25, through 200 (e.g. 101-125, 126-150...176-200)
```

In a dictionary,

```
bin_dict = {0-10 :[0-5, 6-10], 10-100:[11-20, 21-30, ...91-100], 100-200:[101-125, 126-150..]}
```

I tried the following code:

```
def create_bin_ranges(bn_val):
    ## Create a list of bin ranges.
    dict_bin_ranges = {}
    list_bin_ranges = []

    for i in bn_val:
        step = i
        bin_range = np.arange(0, step+i, step)
        list_bin_ranges.append(bin_range)
        dict_bin_ranges[i] = list_bin_ranges
    return dict_bin_ranges
```

Result I get: (This is not what I want)

```
values = create_bin_ranges([5,10,100])
print(values)
>> {5: [array([0, 5]), array([ 0, 10]), array([  0, 100])],
   10: [array([0, 5]), array([ 0, 10]), array([  0, 100])],
   100: [array([0, 5]), array([ 0, 10]), array([  0, 100])]}
```

I am stuck, any suggestion or help would be great.

Comment: What is `bn_val` ?

Comment: Your return statement should not be part of the for-loop.

Comment: What are these values supposed to represent? The step size? The bin size? You need to pass both in order for your function to work.

Comment: Please also explain what your notation `0-5` etc. means. It is not clear. If you think about this, you might be able to come up with the solution yourself.

Comment: @mapf `0-5` is the bin size value as mentioned in the post. `Starting increment is 5, through 10 (e.g. 0-5, 6-10)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what that means. What is a bin size value of `0-5`? What does that look like? Can you please post what such a variable should look like *eactly*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to firstly clearly define the logic behind the bin. One solution is to define a list for all steps where the `range` changes with:

- `start_bin`
- `end_bin`
- `step`

For the example, this leads to:

```
steps = [(0, 10, 5), (10, 100, 10), (100, 200, 25)]
```

Once we know where to go, it's quite easy to build all the bins:

Here, I define a custom function for output keys using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
def f(v1, v2):
    return "{}-{}".format(str(v1), str(v2))
```

Then build the list:

```
# List + dict comprehension
out = {f(min_, max_): [[i+1, i+step] for i in range(min_, max_, step)] for min_, max_, step in steps}

# Or with nested for loops
out = {}
for min_, max_, step in steps:
    bin_ = []
    for i in range(min_, max_, step):
        bin_.append([i+1, i+step])
    out[f(min_, max_)] = bin_
print(out)
```

*output*:

```
# {
#     '0-10': [[1, 5], [6, 10]], 
#     '10-100': [[11, 20], [21, 30], [31, 40], [41, 50], [51, 60], [61, 70], [71, 80], [81, 90], [91, 100]],
#     '100-200': [[101, 125], [126, 150], [151, 175], [176, 200]]
# }
```

Hope that helps!